# Connections on RN42

Tags: bluetooth, msp430

I have been using a SparkFun BlueSMiRF module with a MSP430G2553 chip on a breadboard.  I want to create a custom circuit to have everything on one board.

Here are a few questions before I go about this:

1. Can I connect the Tx and Rx lines from the RN42 directly to the MSP430 without the level shifting circuits since the MSP430 runs on 3.3v as well?
2. Can I leave the RTS and CTS connections on the RN42 floating since I will only be using 9600 bps?
3. I have a Vcc of 3.3V, so I will be removing the voltage regulator circuit at the top left.  (Not really a question, but if I'm doing something wrong here, hopefully someone will point it out).

(SparkFun schematics: http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/BlueSMiRF-Gold-ChipAnt-v1_rotat2.pdf)

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes - but don't forget to connect MSP430 Tx to RN42 Rx, and vice versa.
2. Yes - but you should pull CTS low, or loop it back into RTS via SJ1.
3. OK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Would there be a difference between pulling CTS low and shorting it with RTS?

Comment: Not really, but the jumper's there so you may as well use it.